# Developing Mir GUI on Ubuntu Server

Tags: application-development, gui, mir

The question is:
How would I develop a C++ GUI application using Mir on Ubuntu server?

I've installed all the packages that relate to Mir: mir-demos, unity-system-compositor, libunity-mir-dev, ubuntu-desktop-mir and maybe more.

All I have are mirclient, mircommon, mirplatform, mirserver folder in /usr/include which don't correspond to any of the examples presented on the Mir official page.

Answer (score 0):

Mir is a display server . so it is a low level componet . So you can simply use qt or gtk(under development) for mir display server . binding of mir with these tool kit will do the job . you don't have to worry about it :-)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu server. All I have is pico and g++. Can't this be done in C++ without qt or gtk?